# How to use a many-to-many (belongsToMany) based on another many-to-many relationship?

Tags: php, laravel

I have features that have multiple variants that can be chosen. So when you chose a feature it will come with its choosable variants.

features *table*

```
id    title
--    -----
1     color
2     size
```

feature_variant *table*

```
id    feature_id    variant_id
--    ----------    ----------
1     1             1
2     1             2
3     2             3
4     2             4
```

variants *table*

```
id    title
--    -----
1     red
2     blue
3     small
4     large
```

Feature **Model**

```
public function variants()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ProductFeatureVariant::class, 'feature_id', 'id');
}
```

Variant **Model**

```
public function feature()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Feature::class, 'feature_id', 'id');
}
```

So until here everything is quite simple. Imagine a form where I can select feature for a product and after that all its variants are listed in a dropdown select.

The point I am stuck is to store the **selected** feature and its **selected** variant/s. And after (storing) selecting those I need the data (eager loaded) like product->selected_features->selected_variants.

Both relations **selected_features** and **selected_variants** will need to use the already generated **features** and **variants** with their id, which is necessary because they include other needed data.

so when I create

product_selected_feature *table*

```
id    product_id    feature_id
--    ----------    ----------
1     1             1
2     2             2
```

Product **model**

```
public function selected_features()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Feature::class, 'product_selected_feature', 'product_id', 'feature_id');
}
```

untill here there are no problems as well. I can simply load `Product::with('selected_features')->get();` but when I try to handle the last chain selected_variants I get in trouble.

SelectedFeature **Model**

```
public function selected_variants()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Variant::class, 'feature_selected_variant', 'feature_id', 'feature_id');
}
```

My problem here is that when I attach a selected_variant to a the selected_feature it ignores the product and all products that have the selected_feature (selected) will have all, the same selected_variants. Well which is actually normal regarding to relations (settings) above.

Instead using the feature_id for the relation, I somehow need to base it on the product_selected_feature pivot tables id itself. So that each product has its own selected_feature selected_variants but still use the main features and variants data. I think I am missing something very sipmle here.